# Pandas: number of occurrences in custom time frame and most active times for specific days

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm quite new to Stack and pandas and couldn't find anything like this one, it seems more complex than typical operations, and I'd love to learn how to do this:

```
The data set:

Day       Messages   Time 
Friday    spam       8:05 AM
Tuesday   eggs       8:45 AM
Friday    smapeggs   9:03 AM
Monday    eggseggs   1:05 PM
Tuesday   baz        8:33 AM
Monday    eggsspam   2:25 PM
```

Desired Output 1:

```
Time ranges  Number of Messages
8:00-9:00 AM       3
9:00-10:00 AM      1
1:00-2:30 PM       2
```

Desired Output 2:

```
Day         Most Active Time
Friday         8:00-10:00 AM 
Tuesday        8:00-9:00 AM 
Monday         1:00-2:30 AM
```

The idea is to see what hours are most responsive in general and what hours are most responsive for specific days. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint for pd.cut and groupby count

Comment: You might get a better response if you provide the code for the sample dataframe definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
df_start=pd.DataFrame({ 'Day' :['Friday','Tuesday','Friday','Friday'],
                        'Message':['spam','msg','eggs','another'],
                        'Time':['8:05 AM','9:45 AM', '10:34 AM', '8:45 AM']})
df_start=df_start.set_index('Time')
df_start.index = pd.to_datetime(df_start.index)
df_result=df_start.resample("2h").count().loc[:,'Message']
```

For the second output, try to use the below:

```
df_result=df_start.groupby("Day").apply(lambda df_start: 
                 df_start.resample("2h").count())
```